# Laravel - how to pass variable from controller to job

Tags: laravel

Sorry if this is a noob question.

I used to send emails directly through the controller, like so:

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new RegisterConfirmation($user));
```

As you can see I also pass the $user into the email where I can use that user's information, like "Hello {{$user->username}}!"

But now instead I want to queue emails, so in my controller I now have this:

```
RegisterConfirmationJob::dispatch($user);
```

In my job, I have the following:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function handle()
{
    $user = $this->user;
    Mail::to($user)->send(new RegisterConfirmation($user));
}
```

When I run this, it returns the following error:

> [2021-07-09 20:33:57] local.ERROR: Undefined property:
> App\Jobs\RegisterConfirmationJob::$user {"exception":"[object]
> (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property:
> App\Jobs\RegisterConfirmationJob::$user at
> /home/vagrant/projects/app/Jobs/RegisterConfirmationJob.php:37)
> [stacktrace]

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is my entire RegisterConfirmationJob class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\RegisterConfirmation;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RegisterConfirmationJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        Mail::to($user)->send(new RegisterConfirmation($user));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you defined `$user` property on `RegisterConfirmation` class?

Comment: can you post the entire `RegisterConfirmationJob` class file?

Comment: @DaviMendesDev ok I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah bro, it's not a Laravel problem, it's a PHP class definition problem, you can solve this by declaring the `$user` property, like that:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\RegisterConfirmation;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RegisterConfirmationJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user; // you forgot of put this line

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        Mail::to($user)->send(new RegisterConfirmation($user));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, you hadn't declared $user as a class property, that is the error meaning.

I recommend you declare it as public property to use it at blade template

Comment: How do I declare it as a class? I thought that already happened when I passed "User $user" in __construct?

Comment: Thank you it work for me. Public $yourVariable after class.